# HttpContext Scope when creating Async Task

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ninject, task-parallel-library, httpcontext

If I start an asynchronous task inside an MVC3 Controller action, and then return immediately, is the HttpContext scope until the next Garbage Collection call, or does it wait until the asynchronous task completes before it is garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects are [`Dispose`d](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) (not garbage collected) at the end of [the request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx).